# how to flatten nested observables that results after rxjs from

Tags: rxjs

I want to start with a nested rxjs from([1,2,3,[4,5],6]) and end up with a flattened array by the time I subscribe. Ie: [1,2,3,4,5,6]

here is my attempt

```
from([1,2,3,[4,5],6]).pipe(
   mergeMap(
     item => item || from(item),
     toArray()
   ).subscribe(res => console.log("res", res)
) // want to print [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: You'll have to use something like `typeof item === 'array' ? from(item) : of(item)`

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked.

```js
from([1,2,3,[4,5],6]).pipe(
  mergeMap(
    item => typeof item === 'number' ? of(item) : of(...item)
  ),
  toArray()
).subscribe(res => console.log("res", res))
```

I'm not sure if it is the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using **SCAN**

```
import { from, scan } from 'rxjs';


from([1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6])
 .pipe(
  scan((a, c) => { 
   return Array.isArray(c) ? [...a, ...c ] : [...a, c ]} , []
  ),
  last()
 ).subscribe((res) => console.log('res', res));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vnhxza?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

We can use Array.prototype.flat (unless we need IE support) as well:

```
from([1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6])
  .pipe(
    // Will wait wait until last array element and it will emit the whole array
    toArray(),
    // Array.prototype.flat will flat an array (supported in all browsers except IE)
    map(a => a.flat())
  ).subscribe((res) => console.log('res', res));
```